# How to use Dask Distributed Futures

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a future that is a python set that I broadcasted (`LocalCluster`):

```
In [0]: [set_future] = client.scatter([_set], broadcast=True)

In [1]: set_future

Out[1]: Future: set status: finished, type: builtins.set, key: set-529f704c52fef330450e5d68302fbeac
```

Now I simply want to have that data available in my `map_partitons` op:

```
In [2]: def mapper(pdf, _set):
          assert type(_set)==set
          return pdf

        ddf.map_partitions(mapper, set_future)

Out[2]: AssertionError()
```

However, in the mapper the type is `distributed.client.Future` and not `set`. The future doesn't seem to be recovered from the cluster. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide `meta` to `map_partitions` then Dask will try to infer it w/ dummy data and will actually evaluation your mapping function. However, in this context, the futures don't resolve from the cluster which will cause your function to error.

In summary, if you are using futures, you must provide `meta`.